# eclipse обновить версию для разработки под android для разработки java ee

Tags: android, javascript, eclipse

скачал eclipse от google для разработки под android, можно конечно скачать Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, но хочется иметь все в одном месте

Comment: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/9-urok-2-ustanovka-i-nastrojka-sredy-razrabotki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Они отличаются лишь набором предустановленных плагинов, просто установите из Eclipse Marketplace необходимые вам.